# To hide all rows when value is 0 in column I depending on a dropdown list in Cell D3

Tags: macros, hide

I have a dropdown list in cell D3. Once you change D3 the rows values changes some with numbers over/under 0 and some remain a sharp 0 in column I. I need a Macro which will loop and the result should be that when I change D3, all information with exact 0 value in column I will be hidden, BUT when I change D3 again it will reset and again hide all rows which include a 0 in column I.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a macro with changes on a sheet, you can put a sub on the worksheet, using the
Worskheet.Change event : `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

For looping the "I" Column, there are a few ways to loop through it. We can define the range, and do a `For each` loop, or we can use an iterable.

To avoid looping the entire column, we can find the last use row of the column in a few different ways, `Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row` is one of them.

Checking the value of the cell in the loop is straight forward enough and to hide the row, we can just use `Range.EntireRow.Hidden = True`

The whole thing could look something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim hide As Boolean, i As Long
'Intersect validates that the change is only happening in "D3" to be valid
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
' i = starting range - to - last row    
    For i = 4 To Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
        hide = False
        If Cells(i, 9).Value = "0" Then hide = True
        Cells(i, 9).EntireRow.Hidden = hide
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```